# Pass a function to TextInput defaultValue in ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

hey i want to control the default value on my textInput and for that i want to use ternary operator to show a default depending on the case :

```js
 defaultValue={()=>{metadata[1][0]?metadata[1][0]:""}}
```

but this is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just initialize your text input state with your initial value :

```
const Component = () => {
    const [text, setText] = useState(metadata[1][0]?metadata[1][0]:"")

    return (
        <TextInput value={text} onChangeText={setText}/>
     )
}
```